# How can I repopulate the system's "Recent places" in non-native QFileDialog?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, qt5

I'm building a custom class derived from `QFileDialog`, and I'd like to apply the `DontUseNativeDialog` option. However, this appears to eliminate the "Recent places" section from the file combo box, and I'd like to restore it if possible.

Is there a way to do this without directly accessing the system's list of "recent places" paths and applying them to the dialog via `setHistory()`? The dialog is meant to be used on multiple platforms and this strategy seems like it could get messy. (If there is a platform-independent way to access the system's "recent places" list within PyQt/Python, though, I'm all ears.)

Here is a minimal code sample that will reproduce the issue.

```
w = QFileDialog()
w.setOption(DontUseNativeDialog)
w.show()
```

I have tried `w.setHistory(w.history())`, which adds the current directory to "Recent places", but it doesn't restore the normal ~5 recent directories that I would see in a native dialog. Even before the `DontUseNativeDialog` option is set, `w.history()` will only return the current directory, not the full list of recent places that appears in the native dialog.

UPDATE: I have also tried saving the state of the dialog using `saveState()` before setting the `DontUseNativeDialog` option, e.g.

```
w = QFileDialog()
state = w.saveState()
w.setOption(DontUseNativeDialog)
w.restoreState(state)
```

but `restoreState()` returns `False`, indicating an error.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum example that shows how you've subclassed it, how you instantiate it, etc?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight, I thought that I was unable to edit my question at my current reputation level. I've tried to make it a little more presentable and include the requested information.

Comment: @CraigularJoe. Use [saveState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#saveState) and [restoreState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#restoreState).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @ekhumoro. I tried saving the state before setting the `DontUseNativeDialog` option and restoring it afterward, but it appears to have no effect. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @CraigularJoe. I gave you links to the documentation that explains how to use those methods. If you read them carefully, it should be obvious that you need to do more than simply call those methods.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I'm sorry but I'm still confused. The docs you linked to are very brief, but it is still not obvious to me what I should do with these methods other than saving the dialog state with `state = self.saveState()`, then restoring it later with `self.restoreState(state)`. I don't think the bit about `QSettings` applies in my case, because I'm not trying to make the state persistent.

If it's helpful, `restoreState()` returns `False`, indicating that there was an error when I attempted to run it.

Comment: @CraigularJoe. If you want this to be cross-platform, you *do* need to persist the state, and `QSettings` is probably the best way to do it. If `restoreState` returns `False`, I would guess that indicates `state` is an empty `QByteArray` (i.e. there's no persisted data available). PS: I tested this on arch-linux and it works fine for me.

Comment: @ekhumoro, maybe this will help clear things up. It's not that I want a list of directories that have been used within this specific dialog class. If I open up a vanilla `QFileDialog`, even without persistent settings, "Recent Places" contains five separate directories that I've used recently during other file browsing activities. If that was already understood, then my apologies. Also, I don't think the problem with my saved state is that it's an empty `QByteArray` -- if I try to restore the state before applying `DontUseNativeDialog`, `restoreState()` returns `True`. FWIW, I am using PyQt5.

Comment: @CraigularJoe. In that case, your question seems contradictory. You say you want a platform-independent way to manage the history (which is what `saveState/restoreState` gives you), but then insist on keeping only the platform-specific history. I suppose a crude way to achieve that might be to grab the `history()` from a native dialog, and then use `setHistory()` to transfer it to a non-native one.

Comment: @ekhumoro, sorry for the confusion. I am looking for a platform-independent way to display the history in the same way that an unmodified `QFileDialog` widget displays the history (by using native dialogs). Unfortunately, I've tried calling `history()` from conventional `QFileDialog` instances that show the normal "Recent Places" list-- and they return an empty list.

Comment: @CraigularJoe. Well, you've now confirmed that If you want a custom file-dialog, you can't help yourself to platform-specific features at the same time. That is why Qt provides its own API for persisting state. Is it really so important that you keep the history in sync? Personally, I much prefer to keep the file-dialog history application-specific (speaking as a user).

Comment: @ekhumoro Fair enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to tell you that this "recent" list you're referring to is an operating system specific implementation. The same paths you see there you'd see if you were to launch the explorer (for example).

The non-native dialog displays a specialized UI that displays all the entries you set via setHistory(), but only those.